# I can't manage to do a ComponentScan from a test packages to main packages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

is there anyone who would know the way how to use a **@ComponentScan(basePackages = {})** from class inside "**test**" directory to point on a packages in "**main**" directory.

For instance:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {com.package.inside.main.directory.package1,
      com.package.inside.main.directory.package2 })
public class TestConfiguration{}
```

I tried this way but when i type the package name it doesn't recognize the ones outside the **test** directory

Comment: basePackages expects an array of **Strings**. There is no such thing as a package literal in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? The value of "basePackages" should be a string array. So you can input any string there. Like:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.package.inside.main.directory.package1",
"com.package.inside.main.directory.package2","any package is ok" })
```

Comment: lol, i don't know what was the bug when I did that... but now when i run the same code after restarting IntelliJ it seems to work...
thanks by the way, it was i suppose some bug...